# Isn't "there're" a contraction for "there are"?

Tags: contractions

Aw, don't be silly. Well, I think so. So we'll say, "There're books in the library." We can also say, "We know there're not lots of foods or drinks in the library, but only books."

Comment: Most English speakers use *there's* instead of *they're* nowadays, even when referring to multiple things. "There's a pen, a book and a compass on the table." Search this site for *there is* or *there's*.

Comment: @Clare - That's different.  It's distributing "is" over a list.  And "there're" is used all the time by native English speakers.  (And "they're" is also used, but it means something entirely different.)

Comment: Your second sentence would more properly be "We know there's not a lot of food or drinks in the library, only books."

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be used in spoken English at times (especially in North America), but I never see it in writing.